# Several questions on Simultaneous Equation Models

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics

**Question 1:**

Suppose I want to estimate the model

$$ Y = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 X_2 + \alpha_2 S + e $$
$$ S = \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + e_s $$
where the $Y, S, X_2$ are endogenous. However, from what I understand about SEM is that the equations state a causal relationship between variables. Which is exactly how I constructed equation (1) in the system. But equation (2) is constructed as $S$ being a combination of $X_1$ and $X_2$, such that $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are a share of the total $S$ and $e_s$ is some unknown component.

Can the second equation even be included in an SEM setup?

**Question 2:**

Now if the second equation can be included in the model, and I am only interested in the estimation of $\alpha_1$ in the model, I derived the reduced-form as

$$ Y = \alpha_0^* + \alpha_1^* X_2 + \alpha_2^* X_1 + e^* $$
where
$$ \alpha_0^* = \alpha_0 $$
$$ \alpha_1^* = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \beta_2 $$
$$ \alpha_2^* = \alpha_2 \beta_1 $$
$$ e^* = e + \alpha_2 e_s $$

Clearly, I cannot derive a solution for $\alpha_1$ from these equations. So to minimize the amount of work that I would need to do looking for an instrument and since I am only interested in the identification of $\alpha_1$, I figured the best model to estimate is this one

$$ Y = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 X_2 + \alpha_2 S + e $$
$$ S = \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + e_s $$
$$ X_2 = \gamma_0 IV + e_x $$

When I derived reduced-form for this 3-equation system, I got

$$ Y = \alpha_0^* + \alpha_1^* X_2 + \alpha_2^* X_1 + \alpha_3^* IV + e^* $$
where
$$ \alpha_0^* = \alpha_0 $$
$$ \alpha_1^* = \alpha_1 $$
$$ \alpha_2^* = \alpha_2 \beta_0 $$
$$ \alpha_3^* = \alpha_2 \beta_1 \gamma_0 $$
$$ e^* = e + \alpha_2 (e_s + \beta_1 e_x) $$

I am able to estimate $\alpha_1$, which is my goal. But does this setup even make sense?